# How to replace a character and overwrite the original file

Tags: python, replace, overwrite, python-re

I'm trying to change the `|` symbol with the `_` on a text of a file and overwrite the result.

The text of my file is something like:

```
#Hello there|this is my text_to_modify
```

So as you can see the `_` is already present is some parts of the text but I want to change only the `|` symbol.

The code I wrote is:

```
import re

with open(my_file,'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = re.sub('|', '_', text)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(text)
    f.truncate()
    f.close()
```

and the output is:

```
#Hello_there|this_is_my_text_to_modify
```

What can I do? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe symbol:

`text = re.sub('\|', '_', text)`

`|` has a special meaning in regular expressions ('or') and has to be escaped to be used literally. I don't understand how you got the output you reported, because what your regex `'|'` is basically saying is, 'match nothing or nothing and replace it with an underscore', so your output should have underscores between all of the characters (where 'nothing' is).

I recommend you take a good look at the excellent Python regex documentation.

As a side note, the way you overwrite the original file is very dangerous: If you mess something up, you lose all the content from the original file. Better output into a new file.